# Dont understand minecraft data packets

Tags: networking, minecraft, wireshark, packet, packet-sniffers

I have been trying for hours to understand what minecraft packets mean but they don't seem to adhere to the [protocol](https://wiki.vg/Protocol) I've been using wireshark to sniff the packets and according to the protocol they should start with 0x something but they never do I'm really confused rn and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is some of the data that came with packets:

57 9e e9 f7 7f 3c 0b c7 b2 f0 f2 1d 8e 42 6e

9c 14 57 71 74 6b 83

54 ad d7 3a 51 60 55

any help is really appreciated

Answer (score 2):

`0x` is just a way of telling (almost all language compilers) that the following number is a hex number, `9e` would be written as `0x9e` in Java. There are also other number prefixes, e.g. `0b` means that the following number is binary (`0` and `1`'s).

Comment: @Linearous If this answers your question, please mark it as such.